# If I know apparent planetary positions how do I calculate the date?

Tags: planet, retrograde-orbit

I have planetary position in retrograde  how do I calculate the date?

For eg, I know Mars was in retrograde in Scorpion (Sidereal 210 to 240 deg), how do I calculate the date and year of this?

As of now the only other info I have is that just days before this was a lunar eclipse where Sun was in Libra.

*Just a year or two before this*
Mars was in retrograde in first half of Leo and at this time Jupiter was placed at Capricorn. These are all sidereal observations.

P.S: This is regarding an ancient scripture citation where it was said Mars was in retrograde in Scorpion, current proposed dates range from 500 BC to 6000 BC. This is all the information I have, that Mars was is in retrograde in sidereal scorpion and I want to find possible date of this happening. The iterative approach would take too long, because the span is about thousands of years

Comment: Please be a bit more elaborate on the details and background of your problem. Otherwise a similarily fleshed-out answer would be use the known ephemeris and do an iterative search. Good guide: put as much detail in your question, showing the research you did yourself as you expect in an answer

Comment: @planetmaker thank you for your comment. This is all the information I have, that Mars was is in retrograde in sidereal scorpion and I want to find possible date of this happening. I tried the iterative approach and couldn't find it, because the span could be about thousands of years.

Comment: You have more information :) What is the accuracy you expect and the one of your input data? What's their source? What is the permissible time span, thus what do you try to (dis)prove? Something archeological? Futuristic? Have the dinosaurs seen it? How did you try the iterative approach? And why is it a problem to iterate over thousands of years?

Comment: @planetmaker oh ok, I will update those things

Comment: There are several related questions : https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/can-i-look-at-the-sky-and-find-the-day-of-the-week https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26410/position-of-specific-stars-in-the-sky-as-a-function-of-time https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34860/encode-place-and-date-in-star-pattern https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/is-it-possible-to-determine-an-observers-position-on-earth-from-a-photo-of-the?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You seem to be dripping additional information.  How come you didn't know about the Lunar Eclipse yesterday when you asked the question?  Can you clarify what you mean by "siderial" since scorpio is now between 16h and 18h ra,  or about 240-270 degrees

Comment: @JamesK the thing is I'm a noob,  and I didnt know that Moon and Sun position could be related with Mars's retro in finding out dates. But when Mike in the answer said it Mars retro happens like every 2 yrs and asked for other positions,  then I added it. As for Mars I only have so much info.

Comment: @JamesK yes scorpio is 240 to 270 deg. Well some people use Tropical measurements. So wanted to explicitly differentiate this. Sidereal meaning reported as seen, if you went out and looked at that tine you would actually see Mars in Scorpion.

Answer (score 3):

Mars's ~72 day [retrograde loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_retrograde_motion) occurs every ~2.1 years and intersects a given constellation once or twice [every 15 or 17 years](https://mars.nasa.gov/all-about-mars/night-sky/opposition/).
The more information you have about the positions of other planets, e.g. Jupiter or Saturn, the more you can narrow the set of possible dates.

Comment: So this is very frequent happening. As of now the only other info I have is that just days before this was a lunar eclipse where Sun was in Libra.Just a year or two before this Mars was in retrograde in first half of Leo and at this time Jupiter was placed at  Capricorn. These are all sidereal observations.